# Assign Subcategory to Main Category based on a user defined % Split at subcategory level-Excel Formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a list of Unique IDs which have a Category assigned to them as shown in the table on the left. However, each of the Categories have subcategories as mapped out on the table to the right. A user can specify the % HC Split that each subcategories should be assigned to the ID-Category list. SubCategoryAllocation gives the list number of times each subcat can be assigned.

The desired outcome is the result shown in the column highlighted on the left table.

Is there a way I can realize this with an excel formula or in vba? Please see image for desired outcome.

[image: Screenshot with desired outcome in column C]

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I see that will give me the total allocation for each subcategory. However, how do I further proceed so I can be able to assign the subcategories to the Category and ID  as shown in the left table in column C?

Comment: From your image, are you trying to pull 40% to each ID or are you trying to pull equally weighted amounts of that 40% to each ID?

Comment: The column SubCategory is giving me the number of times to which I should assign a subcategory to a category. e.g A1 will be assigned to the category A - 4 times and A2 will be allocated 3 times and A3 will be allocated times to the category A - total 10 occurrences of category A. The formula I am looking for will give the output as shown in the blue column

Comment: Oh so the blue column is the column you're trying to create, so if it says 4 instances you want the formula to know "Here's an instance of A, give it 4 A1's"?

Comment: precisely! my apology if it was not clear from the question

Comment: No worries, in the future try to explain it as clearly as possible, I apologize for misinterpreting it. This is a tricky one, that I don't think I have an answer for but I'll think about it and see if  I come up with anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LET`

For example, after adding a helper column in F:

```
=LET(x, COUNTIF(I$2:I2, I2),
y, MIN(FILTER($F$2:$F$6, ($B$2:$B$6=$I2)*($F$2:$F$6>=x))),
FILTER($C$2:$C$6, ($F$2:$F$6=y)*($B$2:$B$6=$I2)))
```

The formula for column F I used was `=IFERROR(IF(MATCH($B2, $B1:$B$1, 0)>0, SUMIF($B1:$B$1, $B2, E1:E$1)+$E2), $E2)`, getting the cumulative count on the category.

Call the full dataset `A` and the desired resultant dataset `B`. Then the first function in `LET` , x, determines the number of total instances of the category thus far in `B`. The second function is a workaround to `MATCH`; we want the least upper bound in `A` on the cumulative count from x. The third function finds that row in a filtered array of `A` and returns the subcategory.

[image]

REQUESTED EDIT: For those with older versions of Excel, you can use something like the hideous

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("C"&MATCH($I2, $B$1:$B$6,0)&
":C"&COUNTIF($B$1:$B$6, $I2)+MATCH($I2, $B$1:$B$6,0)-1),

MATCH(MINIFS(INDIRECT("F"&MATCH($I2, $B$1:$B$6,0)&
":F"&COUNTIF($B$1:$B$6, $I2)+MATCH($I2, $B$1:$B$6,0)-1),
INDIRECT("F"&MATCH($I2, $B$1:$B$6,0)&
":F"&COUNTIF($B$1:$B$6, $I2)+MATCH($I2, $B$1:$B$6,0)-1),
">="&COUNTIF(I$2:I2, $I2)), INDIRECT("F"&MATCH($I2, $B$1:$B$6,0)&
":F"&COUNTIF($B$1:$B$6, $I2)+MATCH($I2, $B$1:$B$6,0)-1),0))
```

It follows the same idea, just uses a lot more work to get there. `INDIRECT` is used to create the appropriate ranges as a work around for `FILTER`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However I am using Microsoft Excel 2016. Is it possible to share how the formula will look like in Excel 2016 which does not have Let

Comment: I am having a challenge converting the MINIFS in the formula which is not a function in MS Excel 2016. I have tried with no success: MIN(IF($B$2:$B$6=I2,INDIRECT("F"&MATCH($I2,$B$1:$B$6,0)&":F"&COUNTIF($B$1:$B$6,$I2)+MATCH($I2,$B$1:$B$6,0)-1)))